# how to wait for the second window to load completely

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I click a button from parent window and it loads a viewer in the new(child) window, then i do some action in the second window. Here before loading of my second window itself, the script tries to do some action and it fails. If i put `Thred.sleep` it goes successfully. But i do not want to use thread.sleep. Is there any way we can do to wait for SECOND/CHILD window to load its page completely. Here my second window(browser) is a PDF kind of viewer. Below is the code i tried.

```
WebElement row = ele.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr[data-ri=\"0\"]"));
row.findElement(By.className("ui-selection-column")).click();
browser.findElement(By.id("frmResults:btnViewer")).click();

Thread.sleep(5000);

Set<String> AllWindowHandles = browser.getWindowHandles();
String window1 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0];
scenario.write("Currently in Parent Window = "+ AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0]);
scenario.write(browser.getCurrentUrl());
scenario.write(browser.getTitle());

String window2 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1]; // out of bounds error thrown here

scenario.write("Switching to Child (Viewer) window = "+ AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1]);
browser.switchTo().window(window2);
scenario.write(browser.getCurrentUrl());
scenario.write(browser.getTitle());
WebElement viewer = browser.findElement(By.id("outerDiv"));
assertThat(viewer.isDisplayed()).isTrue();
//browser.close();

scenario.write("Again Switching back to Parent window = "+ AllWindowHandles.toArray()[0]);
browser.switchTo().window(window1);
scenario.write(browser.getCurrentUrl());
scenario.write(browser.getTitle());
```

**Updated**

I get the error when i try to get the child window number on this line.

```
String window2 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1];
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at Steps.Steps.verify_the_test_records_are_displayed_in_the_results_table_in_Search_Results_page(Steps.java:115)
        at ?.Then Verify the test records are displayed in the results table in Search Results page(Test.feature:10)

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 30.552 s <<< FAILURE! - in Runner.TestRunner
[ERROR] feature(Runner.TestRunner)  Time elapsed: 29.389 s  <<< FAILURE!
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `thread.sleep()`, you can use the `ExpectedConditions` class to add a targeted explicit wait on the [number of expected windows](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe-int-):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe;
// we need the above using statements to use WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions

// first wait for number of windows to be 2:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2)));

// switch to a new window
String window2 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1];
scenario.write("Switching to Child (Viewer) window = "+ AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1]);
browser.switchTo().window(window2);

// wait on some element on the page to be fully loaded
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("outerDiv")));
```

`ExpectedConditions` should wait on 2 windows to exist before calling `String window2 = (String) AllWindowHandles.toArray()[1];` -- this should ensure `browser.getWindowHandles()` returns `2` before attempting to switch to the second window.

Comment: Yes, i get this logic and i am aware of it. But the error which i get before itself. I have updated my question with the error and the line where i get that too. Please look into it and help me.

Comment: @mmar I think I understand your issue now. `ExpectedConditions` implements a `numberOfWindowsToBe` method, where you can wait for the number of windows to be 2 before calling `switchTo().window(window2)`, to avoid the out of bounds exception.

Comment: Yes. When i output ```scenario.write(String.valueOf(AllWindowHandles.size()));```, the ```AllWindowHandles``` is having the size as '1'.

Comment: That makes sense, I see what you mean now. I've updated my sample with an alternate solution to wait on 2 windows to exist.

Comment: Yes. you made it. It works fine now. I put this Explicit wait before this line ```Set<String> AllWindowHandles = browser.getWindowHandles();``` and it waits and get all the expected windows before it moves to next action and am able to wait, load and do action on the new window. Thank you so much. I accepted your answer too.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. The link to the `ExpectedConditions` documentation I linked provides implementations for many other conditions as well, so hopefully you can use those in your future automation.